# Zero argument function template explicit instantiation does not seem to work

Tags: c++

I just started learning template programming. I understand one can instantiate a function template in two ways that's expilicit and implicit. Consider below code.

```
template <typename var>
void cool(){
   var y = 45;
   int i = 2;
}

template void cool<int>(); // instantiated here

int main(){
  cool(); // error no matching function call. why?
  cool<int>(); // works. whats the difference between both?
  return 0;
}
```

When I use zero argument function template,  I get `error: no matching function call for cool()` even when I explicitly instantiate it. but this is not the case when I use arguments as shown below

```
template <typename var>
void cool(var x){
   var y = 45;
   int i = 2;
}

template void cool<int>(int); // instantiated here

int main(){
  cool(24); // works
  return 0;
}
```

I understand explicit instantation works only when function arguments have template types. and it is ignored if function has no template types in its argument list. is that right? or is there anything I am missing out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit instantiation doesn't magicaly give the compiler the means to guess what a template argument should be. Also, consider:

```
template <typename var>
void cool(){
   var y = 45;
   int i = 2;
}

template void cool<int>();
template void cool<char>();

int main()
{             // now, even if explicitions specializations did
              // what you think they do,
    cool();   // what should var be here, int or char?
}
```

Explicit instantiation just forces the instantiation so that, elsewhere, you can get away with declaration only. If there are no means to deduce template arguments, you need to specify them explicitly.

That's why your second example works, the template argument can be deduced from the call. Explicit specialization has little to do with it, you can remove it and it'll work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate a one-parameter template with no arguments. Arguments can sometimes be *deduced* so you don't need to provide them *explicitly*, but you still need to provide them. In your case, though, none of the template argument are deducible (since none of them appear as part of function parameter types), so you have to specify all arguments yourself.